# PHP includes file for CSS and JS links in index.php

Tags: javascript, php, css, head

How to include head section with JS and CSS links in index php from another php file e.g-'links.php'?

Answer (score 2):

Quite easy actually

#### index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <?php require_once('header.php'); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### header.php

```
echo "<link href=\"style.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js.js\"></script>";
echo "<link href=\"style2.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">";
```

Comment: that really helped +1

Comment: actually doubles quotes return error, single quotes return results, may i know the diff? @Peter

Comment: @Gem In this case there's nor really a difference between single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Index.php**

```
<html>
    <?php include_once('links.php'); ?>
    <body>
        <!--Your following Code-->
    </body>
</html>
```

**Links.php**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" href="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

**another.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include 'another.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>
// Content goes here
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to include all your files at the top and store their css files and script files within an array. So it could look like something like this:

links.php:

```
return [
    'css' => ['assets/links.css', 'assets/global.css'],
    'js' => ['assets/links.js', 'assets/global.js'],
    'content' => ...
];
```

index.php:

```
// this one requires all.css and all.js
$allCss = ['assets/all.css'];
$allJs = ['assets/all.js'];

$links = include('links.php');

$allCss = array_unique(array_merge($allCss, $links['css']));
$allJs = array_unique(array_merge($allJs, $links['js']));

// Do all rendering below this

// render head something like this
foreach ($allCss as $css) { echo "<link rel=... src=$css />" }
// same for js

// render links: e.g. echo $links['content'];
```

This way, you can have each component specify which files it needs, and if two files need the same css or js file, you won't put a link tag in twice.

This would require you to have some sort of file structure that could support this. My example probably isn't the best one.

Answer (score 0):

try this code this is simple demo for your question implementation may vary as per requirement

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include('path/to/assets.php') ?>
<link href="path/to/this/page/levelcss.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="path/to/this/page/levelscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <!--HTML Body goes here -->
</body>
</html>
```

assets.php

```
<?php 

echo '<link href="path/to/project/levelscript.js" rel="stylesheet">';
echo '<script src="path/to/project/levelscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';

?>
```